# Update table after commit transaction, but need to rollback update and committed insert if update fails

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a C# application that allows users to submit an application form.  The application asks for parent names and if they are married.  Once submitted, a new user record is created for each parent.  If the parents are married, I need to update the SpouseID field in each of the new user records with the ID of the other parent.  See example table below:

```
ID  FirstName  LastName  SpouseID
---------------------------------
1   John       Smith     2
2   Jenny      Smith     1
3   Jim        Jackson   NULL
```

Currently, my code is wrapped in a begin try statement, so I'm unable to update the SpouseID field with the newly created users IDs until the insert statement has been committed.  I can move the statement to update the SpouseID fields to after the COMMIT TRANSACTION statement, but I still want to be able to roll back everything if there's an issue updating the SpouseID fields.

Is this possible?  Any ideas of how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

I've included a simplified version of the stored procedure code.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY

    SET @OuterTransFlag = @@TRANCOUNT

    IF @OuterTransFlag = 0 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            IF (@UserIDP1 = 0) 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Users (Surname, Given1)
                    SELECT ISNULL(Surname, ''), ISNULL(GivenName, '')
                    FROM ParentInfo_Processed
                    WHERE CODE = @Code 

                    SET @Parent1ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                END 

            IF (@UserIDP2 = 0) 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Users (Surname, Given1)
                    SELECT ISNULL(Surname, ''), ISNULL(GivenName, '')
                    FROM ParentInfo_Processed
                    WHERE CODE = @Code 

                    SET @Parent2ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                END 

        IF (@ParentStatus = 'M')
            BEGIN                                           
                UPDATE Users 
                SET SpouseID = @Parent1ID 
                WHERE ID = @Parent2ID   

                UPDATE Users 
                SET SpouseID = @Parent2ID
                WHERE ID = @Parent1ID   
            END

    IF @OuterTransFlag = 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT <> 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @em VARCHAR(2000)
    SET     @em = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    IF @OuterTransFlag = 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    IF ISNULL(@em, '') <> ''
        RAISERROR(@em, 16, 1)
        RETURN(-1)
END CATCH
```

Comment: Transactions work by incrementing/decrementing @@trancount, as you clearly know. You can either nest your transactions appropriately, or nest your SqlConnection.Command.Excute() calls. Is there a reason these aren't working?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks dylanthelion.  I obviously need to do more research on properly nesting transactions.  I've taken over someone else's project and didn't even think about possibly addressing it in the application.  I've just been troubleshooting all the errors in the stored proc.

Comment: "I'm unable to update the SpouseID field with the newly created users IDs until the insert statement has been committed" - that shouldn't be so. The code you've shown should work fine. *inside* the transaction you can see your own changes, you don't need them committed to allow updates.

Comment: On a separate note, have you considered a different model which doesn't have this redundancy/opportunity for inconsistency? What if row 1 has a SpouseID of 3 but row 3 has a SpouseID which is null or contains a value *other* than 1? A separate table `SPOUSES (LowPersonID, HighPersonID, CHECK(LowPersonID<HighPersonID), UNIQUE(LowPersonID,HighPersonID))` ensures that the data is stored once and consistently.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever - Hmm, that's interesting.  I'm unsure why it's not working then.  More exploration required.  As for the model, I'm bound by the current one as it's third party software. :/

Comment: Just a quick thank you to every one for commenting.  I've since worked out the issue.  It was due to a trigger on the users table.  My original code was updating the spouse before the "primary" parent, which was conflicting with the logic in the trigger.  By swapping the order, I was able to insert the new parents and then update their spouse IDs all in the same transaction.